# Are GNU backtrace_symbols() and dladdr() thread-safe?

Tags: c, multithreading, gnu

I am writing a C++ exception class, which has to provide limited backtrace at throw site. Since my application will be multi-threaded, exceptions might be thrown at the same time. I searched the Internet for this thread-safety issue, but found none.

`backtrace()` returns array of C strings. These C strings must not be freed by the application. Since it gets its information and composites these strings at runtime, I fear that it is not thread safe.

`dladdr()` returns a `struct Dl_info`, with two C strings in it. Also must not be freed by the application.

Oh well, I guess I should just read the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Backtraces.html)

> A backtrace is a list of the function calls that are currently active in a **thread**. The usual way to inspect a backtrace of a program is to use an external debugger such as gdb. However, sometimes it is useful to obtain a backtrace programmatically from within a program, e.g., for the purposes of logging or diagnostics.
>
> The header file execinfo.h declares three functions that obtain and manipulate backtraces of the **current thread**.

Looks like they're using [thread-local storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage).

`dladdr` is returning non-modifiable strings which belong to the loaded object file. This is thread-safe because it's read-only and the object is available until `dlclose`.

Comment: In case your object may be passed among threads (ex. logging thread), you may wish to copy the data first.